# parent loop's itemNumber value in jQuery jsrender.js & jquery.views.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I have using jQuery template using jsrender.js & jquery.views.js by http://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews

I have 1 nested loop and inside teh nested loop i want the get itemNumber or some other value.
Eg:

Template:

```
{{#each ImageQuestions}}
  <div id="image-{{=$view.itemNumber}}">
  {{#each GroupImagesRepeatation}}
    <input type="radio" name="{{=$view.parent.data.QuestionID}}" value="{{=$view.itemNumber}}" />
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Array:

```
var Questions = {
        ImageQuestions: [
                            { 
                                QuestionID: 1,
                                GroupImagesRepeatation: [1, 2, 3, 4]
                            },
                            {
                                QuestionID: 2,
                                GroupImagesRepeatation: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
                            }
                        ]
    };
```

Query: `{{=$view.parent.data.QuestionID}}` is what i want to work correctly. I require to give unique name to radioList for each nested loop.

Please assist me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason `{{=$view.parent.data.QuestionID}}` is not returning the correct value is because you need to step up through two parent levels: `{{=$view.parent.parent.data.QuestionID}}`.
The immediate parent has as data the GroupImagesRepeatation array. Its parent is the data item of the outer each loop - which has a questionID property.

You can use a more compact syntax:

```
{{#each ImageQuestions}}
  <div id="image-{{=$itemNumber}}">
    {{#each GroupImagesRepeatation}}
      <input type="radio" name="{{=$parent.parent.data.QuestionID}}" value="  {{=$itemNumber}}" />
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

A tip - for debugging within the compiled template:
Set `$.views.allowCode = true;` and then add `{{*debugger;}}` within the template, e.g. `{{*debugger;}}<input type="radio" ...`.

Comment: I am using $.views.allowCode = true; , but didn't know that we could actually fire the debugger from it.. Amazing tip.. Thanks a lot of taking time to answer the query at my request.